# Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute [ATTRIBUTENAME] used with directive '[DIRECTIVENAME]' is non-assignable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I'm trying to transform date inside the directive's body I get error:

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute
>   [ATTRIBUTENAME] used with directive '[DIRECTIVENAME]' is
>   non-assignable!

I am using angular version 1.4.14

Expected result: in my template directive  will return class name -

> div class="news-block-container  sm-padding-right"

What can cause this problem? Thanks for your answer

here is an example of my code:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('test.directives')
    .directive('test', function () {
        var templatePath = "/views/templates/testTemplate.tmpl.html";
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                position: '=',
            },
            templateUrl: templatePath,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('position', function () {
                        if (scope.position === "left") {
                            scope.position = "sm-padding-right";
                        }
                        else {
                            scope.position = "sm-padding-left";
                        }
                    });
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
view - directive usage
 <test-template position="'left'"></test-template>



//!TEMPLATE! - testTemplate
<div>
    <a href="{{#}}">
        <div class="news-block-container  {{position}}">           
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ng-class` directive to assign class dynamically

```
<div>
    <a href="{{#}}">
        <div class="news-block-container" ng-class="position">           
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

change `angular.module('test.directives')`

to this `angular.module('test.directives',[])`

Also remove the curly brackets around hash in template

change `<a href="{{#}}">`

to this `<a href="#">`

Comment: No, unfortunately it is still reproducing. Same error: 'Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression ''left'' in attribute 'position' used with directive 'testTemplate' is non-assignable!'

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. I see that your demo is working. And I made all the corrections as you said, but still having this issue. Maybe you have any other ideas why it can be? I tried my version of angular with your demo and it's working

Comment: can u create your own plnkr

Comment: Yep, i will try

Comment: I don't think that I will be able to reproduce all the nuances of this big project. And also I understand that you can't help me without this information. Any way thank you and if no one answers me in a few hours I will choose your answer as correct one.

Comment: it's difficult t figure out whats wrong without further information. anyway hope u will find a answer soon

Comment: I thought that this error is some kind of well-known issue which connected with something specific.

Comment: did you also change `<test-template position="'left'"></test-template>` to this `<test position="'left'"></test>`

Comment: Yes. I have changed it. I want to add, that this logic works well in my template: <div class="news-block-container  {{position == 'left' ? 'sm-padding-right' : 'sm-padding-left'}}" >

Comment: then it should work. difficult to say without the whole picture

Comment: I guess I found solution to my problem. I have changed my scope to : **scope: {position: '@'}**

Comment: @MaximusDredoff Thanks a lot for sharing your solution! I'm debugging this for hours now - your comment made it easy to solve it :)